# Downloading very large results from query via Java Webapp

Tags: java, performance, servlets

I have been mulling over a bit of an issue, and I was wondering if anyone had any advice.
I have a web application that I need to add a section for reporting to. It will have a t-sql query constructed based on user gui inputs, execute, and allow the user to download the file to their computer through their browser as a csv. On it's own none of this is overly complicated. I have done these things before. There is one issue I have not grappled with before however. The results may end up as multiple GBs worth of data. What would I do differently (in terms of code) from normal to prevent it from overloading the browser or being tremendously slow? It clearly cannot all be held in memory at once? How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: What about opening a fileoutput stream in the server's disk, then writing your results into a file, then providing the user with a file download url?

Comment: Concerned with memory consumption for client or server side? Streaming the content sound like an option here. But gigabytes of cvs sound verbose...

Comment: The best option would be to write the data directly to the OutputStream of the incoming request - no intermediate file included. You will have to change your implementation to do that.

Comment: @Jocke It is very verbose but necessary. This is for analysis of sensor data that is taken by hundreds of sensors every minute. There is no way to avoid large quantities of data unfortunately.

Comment: @codeflush.dev I don't think I've done something like that in a long time. Do you know if there are there any examples somewhere I could look at?

Comment: @NatanAndrews do you work with a framework (e.g. Spring-Boot) to build your Webapp or plain JEE-Servlet-API ?

Comment: @codeflush.dev I use mostly JPA Ecliplselink for JDBC mapping, beyond that it;s mostly plain JEE, Just servlets, jsps and java classes. No special frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the csv-data directly to the OutputStream of the incoming request:

```java
package example;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private final CSVCreator csvCreator;

    private MyServlet(CSVCreator csvCreator) {
        this.csvCreator = csvCreator;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // be nice to your consumer, tell them what they get
        resp.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/comma-separated-values; charset=UTF-8");

        try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(resp.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            this.csvCreator.createCSV("some params you need to create the correct csv", writer);
        }
    }
}
```

You will have to change your csv-generation to be able to write to an Writer ... for example:

```java
package example;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CSVCreator {

    public void createCSV(String someParamsYouNeedToCreateTheCSV, Appendable appendable) throws IOException {
        appendable.append("Column1,Column2,Column3\n");
        appendable.append("Row1,Row1,Row1\n");
        appendable.append("Row2,Row2,Row2\n");
    }
}
```

You could also, for example, use apache-commons-csv to write the csv to the given Appendable (see: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.commons/commons-csv/latest/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVPrinter.html )

```java
package example;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CSVCreator {

    public void createCSV(String someParamsYouNeedToCreateTheCSV, Appendable appendable) throws IOException {
        try (CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(appendable, CSVFormat.DEFAULT)) {
            printer.printRecord("Column1", "Column2", "Column3");
            printer.printRecord("Row1", "Row1", "Row1");
            printer.printRecord("Row2", "Row2", "Row2");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

You can create a CSV-File from a ResultSet like this:

```java
package example;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ResultSetToCSV {

    public void createCSV(ResultSet rs, Appendable appendable) throws IOException, SQLException {
        final ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        final int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();

        try (CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(appendable, CSVFormat.DEFAULT)) {
            printHeaders(metaData, columnCount, printer);
            printValues(rs, columnCount, printer);
        }
    }

    private void printHeaders(ResultSetMetaData metaData, int columnCount, CSVPrinter printer) throws IOException, SQLException {
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            printer.print(metaData.getColumnLabel(i));
        }

        printer.println();
    }

    private void printValues(ResultSet rs, int columnCount, CSVPrinter printer) throws IOException, SQLException {
        while (rs.next()) {
            printValue(rs, columnCount, printer);
        }
    }

    private void printValue(ResultSet rs, int columnCount, CSVPrinter printer) throws IOException, SQLException {
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            printer.print(rs.getString(i));
        }

        printer.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll see about doing something like this. Can I plug the result set of the query into the output stream? Or would that blow up? because I can probably get that to come out, already comma delimited.

Comment: @NatanAndrews you can do it however you want. Can you show me your current ResultSet-Processing?

Comment: I can when I have it finished building it, I'm mostly gathering ideas for the methodology as large file transfers are a new area for me.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. This is amazing

Comment: for some reason the end result is an empty file. no file extension, 0 bytes.

Comment: It's resolved. It was something else entirely. needed a new classpath for the driver. It's working like a charm now with something akin to your code. Very much appreciated